# AudioKit Lifecyle confusion

Tags: ios, audiokit

I can't wrap my head around this. I read everywhere (rightly) that Audiokit lifecyle should be managed in a singleton and kept away from the View Controllers lifecyle. Then I checked all the example project's code and found a bit confusing that

```
AudioKit.start()
```

is always called in `ViewDidload`. But anyway thats not my real issue..

I have multiple ViewControllers that uses the `AKMicrophone` in a different way. For instance they need different categories, different AKSettings, and some must be plain microphones while some needs a long chain of initialization with effects and mixers (**Just like the** "Recorder" example project).

I have two related questions here:

- I [read](https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/issues/1603) on Github that when we change the routing or category, we need to reinitialize the AudioKit. But in this case where do we really do it? In my case I really only can think of "`ViewWillAppear`". (if Mic needs to start listening without needing a button click, with a different setup)
- And real question is how do I do this correctly at all? For example in my project AKMicrophone is set up just like the "Recorder" example but in a **Singleton** class. And when I switch to another ViewController which requires a "plain" AKMicrohone right after view appears. How do I remove all those mixers and delays from the chain? This is not only a matter of changing some AKSetting and restarting the engine.

Comment: I'm having trouble fully understanding what you're asking but it shouldn't matter too much where you mess with AudioKit. If you need to change the signal chain you should be able to "hot swap" nodes that are connected to a mixer that connected to the mic output.